# Getting error when trying to Create Subscription from subscribe button of paypal

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to subscribe paypal billing plan from subscribe Buttons. But continuously I am getting error "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.". This is working using sandbox paypal account but not working using paypal live account

`paypal.Buttons({
style: {
shape: 'rect',
color: 'gold',[text](https://stackoverflow.com)
layout: 'vertical',
label: 'subscribe'
},
createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
console.log("subscription created")
let startDt = new Date();
startDt.setDate(startDt.getDate() + 14);

```
            return actions.subscription.create({
                plan_id: plan.product_id,
                ...(trialFlag ? { start_time: startDt } : {})
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            console.log('data',data);
            data.planDetail = plan
            data.trialFlag = trialFlag
            createSubscription(data);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-'+plan.product_id);
```

`

[Subscription Api response error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tkKp.png)

Can some help me to resolve this.

Comment: USER_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED means... the PayPal account is restricted, and cannot send or receive any payments. Sign into www.paypal.com to review details about the restriction, and contact PayPal's customer support if necessary.